# Is there a way to parse messages in Grafana with elasticsearch as the source?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I am using Grafana v7.2.0 with Elasticsearch as a data source.
My logs look like

```
{
  "message": "Counter: 10",
  "id": "Rd57OnsBW_gLMXbXxjMh",
  "level": "info"
}
```

My aim is to filter out logs with values of counter > 5.
I am able to filter out logs with non zero values using

```
"Counter" NOT "Counter: 0"
```

1. How can I filter out values of counter > 5
2. Is there a way I can group these logs by id and take the max value of counter for each id?